# Why does this 2D Array in Java fail?

Tags: java

i am trying to programm the Pascal-triangle in Java. This is my code:

```
public class Matrix {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int Zeilen = 10;
    int Spalten = 10;
    int[][] Matrix = new int[Zeilen][Spalten];

    for(int k=0;k<Zeilen-1;k++) {
        // Gebe jede Zeile aus
        for(int n=0;n<Spalten-1;n++) {
            // Gib jede Spalte aus


            if(n > k) {
                // Für die leeren Felder
                Matrix[k][n] = 0;
            }
            else if(n == k) {
                // Für die Diagonale
                Matrix[k][n] = 1;
            }
            else if(n == 0) {
                // Erste Spalte
                Matrix[k][n] = 1;
            }
            else {
                // Für alle normalen Felder
                System.out.println("TEST");
                Matrix[k+1][n+1] = Matrix[k][n] + Matrix[k][n+1];
            }
        }           
    }

    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<Zeilen;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<Zeilen;j++) {
            System.out.print(Matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
 }
```

It works with the only exception that the computed valued in the last else() part are not saved into the Matrix. Why is that and what exactly is the solution? I am not that good in Java. Thanks for your help.

(Btw: The last else() Part gets executed, the formula should be correct, so its about about the saving into the Matrix).

Comment: What exception you got?

Comment: Note : Even if it's a square 2D array, `for(j=0;j<Zeilen;j++)` should be `for(j=0;j<Spalten;j++)`

Comment: Variable names should start with lower-case letter in Java by [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Your `Matrix[0][0]` will be always `0`.

Comment: I dont get any Exception, it gives me a normal triangle back with the only problem that the cells inside the pyrimade are 0 instead of containing a normal value. Which means that my last else() somehow fails. Why?

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition, you can get the coefficient at the row n and column k by the formula :

[image]

The problem is here (k and n are switched with how you defined the nested loops and the formula you see but that's ok):

```
Matrix[k+1][n+1] = Matrix[k][n] + Matrix[k][n+1];
```

should be:

```
Matrix[k][n] = Matrix[k-1][n-1] + Matrix[k-1][n];
```

Also to fill all your array the for loop should be :

```
for(int k=0;k<Zeilen;k++) {
        // Gebe jede Zeile aus
        for(int n=0;n<Spalten;n++) {
```

Output :

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 3 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 4 6 4 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 5 10 10 5 1 0 0 0 0 
1 6 15 20 15 6 1 0 0 0 
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 0 0 
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 0 
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

[**Demo here.**](http://ideone.com/5CZkDQ)